# position bars grouped bar plot matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, bar-chart

In the following plot

```
y = [2 2 3; 2 5 6; 2 8 9; 2 11 12];
bar(y)
```

[image]

How can I retrieve the position of each bar in order to super impose a marker?

for example I would like to put a star on top of the 2nd (2nd bar of first group) and 5th (2nd bar of second group) bars.

I would prefer a solution that allows me to modify the plot once created..
(given the fig.)
Thanks

Comment: This should help http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/129900-data-labels-above-bars-on-grouped-bar-plot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Xdata and Ydata to do this :

```
y = [2 2 3; 2 5 6; 2 8 9; 2 11 12];
h=bar(y);

% getting xdata and ydata from second bar in each group
xdata= get (h(2),'XData');
ydata= get (h(2),'YData');

% plot a * on second bar from second group
hold on;
offset=0.25;
plot(xdata(2),ydata(2)+offset,'-*');
```

[image]

If you want to mark a bar in center of group, this method works but if you wanted to mark for example a first one of one group you have to adjust the position of the * with a offset value in x axis.

for example I want to mark the third bar of second group :

```
y = [2 2 3; 2 5 6; 2 8 9; 2 11 12];
h=bar(y);

% getting xdata and ydata from second bar in each group
xdata= get (h(3),'XData');
ydata= get (h(3),'YData');

% plot a * on second bar from second group
hold on;
offset=0.25;
xoffset = 0.23; % manual set of get from properties of bar handle
plot(xdata(2)+xoffset,ydata(2)+offset,'-*');
```

[image]